# Usar ventana modal para inicio de sesión con Devise en Rails

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, modal

bueno mi problema es que he estado intentando implementar una ventana modal con **Bootstrap** y la gema **Devise** en Rails, la verdad he probado ya una gran cantidad de formas que he visto por Internet y ninguna me ha dado una solución en concreto. Ok aquí  coloco lo que actualmente he hecho.

Primero he creado un nuevo controlado llamado **my_session**. Este controlador extiende de la clase devise. Este es el **codigo**.

```
class MySessionController < Devise::SessionsController
end
```

Después he ido al archivo **routes.rb** y le he dicho a devise a través de la siguiente línea de código que utilice este nuevo controlador para todo lo que tenga que ver con las sesiones de usuario.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'my_session'}
```

Esto genera las siguiente rutas.

```
   Prefix Verb                   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
    new_user_session GET          /users/sign_in(.:format)       my_session#new
    user_session POST             /users/sign_in(.:format)       my_session#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)      my_session#destroy
```

Con lo que respecta a la implementación de la ventana modal, he creado un archivo llamado **new.js.erb** que esta dentro del directorio **my_session**, este directorio se crear al generar el controlador **my_session**. Ok Este archivo contiene el siguiente código JavaScrtip.

```
$('<%= j render "new" %>').modal('show');
```

Esto debería hacer render de un archivo parcial llamado **_new.html.erb** que esta bajo el mismo directorio. Este archivo parcial es el que contiene el código de la ventana modal y el formulario de inicio de sesión. El archivo **_new.htm.erb** contiene lo siguiente.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Inicio de sesión</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), remote: true) do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :correo_electronico %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :contraseña %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
                <%= f.label :recordarme %>
            </div>
        <% end -%>

        <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Iniciar sesión", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Ahora para llamar al archivo **new.js.erb** he agregado un método **new** en el controlador **my_session** que responde en formato js o html. Aquí el codigo.

```
class MySessionController < Devise::SessionsController
    def new 
       super
       respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html
       end
    end
end
```

Ahora aquí esta el enlace que llama al método **new**. Este enlace se encuentra en un directorio **home**, en un archivo parcial llamado **_header.html.erb** que contiene una navegación hecha con Bootstrap y es la que contiene este enlace.

```
<%= link_to "Iniciar sesión", new_user_session_path, remote: true %>
```

El archivo parcial **_header.html.erb** es renderizado en el archivo **application.html.erb** que esta bajo el directorio **layout**. Aquí el código.

```
<%= render "home/header"%>
```

Ok al hacer clic sobre el enlace de **iniciar sesión** me genera el siguiente error.

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2016-11-25 12:10:48 -0400
Processing by MySessionController#new as JS
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Rendered home/_header.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 430ms (Views: 431.9ms | ActiveRecord:  0.0ms)

AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after   redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".)
:app/controllers/my_session_controller.rb:4:in `new'
```

En la consola de Google Chrome me sale lo siguiente:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Intente cambiando el orden de respuesta en el método **new** del controlador **my_session**, es decir primero **format.html** y después **format.js** pero tampoco funciono.

Con lo que respecta al archivo **Gemfile** tengo lo siguiente:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
gem 'bootstrap-modal-rails', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.5'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.1'
gem 'bootstrap-select-wrapper-rails', '~> 1.10'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 2.1'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'

group :development, :test do
   gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
   gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

El archivo **application.js** tiene la siguiente configuración.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-select
//= require bootstrap-modal
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree.
```

Así que esto es lo que tengo actualmente para la implementación de la ventana modal en Rails. Como dije en al principio he intentado ya varias formas de hacerlo y no lo he logrado. Aquí dejo un enlace del cual me he estado guiando.

http://blog.makeitreal.camp/modales-bootstrap-ruby-on-rails/

OJO no quiero decir que la solución planteada en esa página sea mala, simplemente a mi no me ha funcionado esta solución. Espero alguien me pueda echar una mano con esto, es para un proyecto personal. Ok gracias.

Comment: el error dice que se está llamando a render 2 veces, seguramente sea porque en tu método llamás primero a super (que termina invocando un render) y luego hacés un respond_to do |format| y terminás haciendo render otra vez, me suena a que no es realmente necesario que hagas tu propio método, con implementar la vista .js.erb ya debería alcanzar, sin hacer override del action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dice @arieljuod, el problema es que efectivamente al llamar a `super` estás llamando [al `respond_with` de la clase padre](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L12) y luego vuelves a llamar a `respond_to`, lo que provoca el error. Si tu objetivo de sobreescribir `sessions_controller` es tan solo para que responda a llamadas json, creo que con esto debería ser suficiente:

```
class MySessionController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :html, :json
end
```

Si no te dio resultado, podrías probar a copiar/pegar el código del [`sessions_controller` original](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L8):

```
  def new
    self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
  end
```

y modificarlo de acuerdo a tus necesidades.

Comment: Que tal, he hecho lo que dijiste en el controlador **my_seesion**, pero ahora al hacer clic sobre el enlace llama a la vista **new.html.erb** de **devise** en el directorio **sessions** y no al archivo **new.js.erb**.

Comment: Esto fue lo que me funciono para llamar al archivo **new.js.erb** desde el controlador.                                                                                                                                                                                   `self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
     respond_to do |format|
 format.js {
  render :template => "../views/my_session/new.js.erb", format: :js
 }
 end`                                                                                                    Muchas gracias por sus respuestas. @arieljuod y After Lagos.

Comment: @halexgs Que bueno que resolviste, de todas formas podrías probar a usar `<%= link_to "Iniciar sesión", new_user_session_path(format: :json), remote: true %>` con la solución que te mencioné a ver si te funciona. Saludos